# What does "queue segment (1796152) as segment duration will go beyond buffer limit" mean?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Recently I started getting user complaints while playing m3u8 videos. On everyone of those cases the symptoms are that the Chromecast sits there attempting to load the video and it never loads. On the Chromecast console I see this error for every single one of the videos the users have sent to me:

media_player.js:23  [ 11.182s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: queue segment (1796152) as segment duration will go beyond buffer limit

What does that error mean? Also why is it happening all of the sudden? the users claim those same exact videos used to work just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: We would definitely like to get this issue addressed but need a bit of info from you. First, what is the typical size/duration of your segments? Also, can you provide a stream that exhibits this issue so we can repro that and get it addressed? We have made some changes to avoid running into memory issues and that is why we need to make sure our approach is working correctly.

Comment: This stream reproduces the issue https://f9124e89e1bae6941de4-debc7f18fd23deaa62dcd684d286782a.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/master.m3u8 but please let me know once you are done so I can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the stream, please feel free to tear down the stream. See the Answer section for a long response to your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed message, in general, may not necessarily point to an issue but in some cases it does, such as yours. Certain changes were made into MPL to help managing the memory on the cast device; that was mostly done to avoid running into memory issues for streams with very large segments, large enough that they could potentially cause issues if they were to be added to the buffer. In your particular case, your segments are sometimes larger than 20 seconds long and that had triggered the new logic. We are improving our logic to manage larger segments in a less aggressive manner and the fix for that will be in the next MPL release. Meanwhile, if you can, we suggest you shorten the length of your segments, which, in general, is recommended to be not more than 10 or at most 15 seconds.

Comment: @ali naddaf what else could this be? Our segments are 6s (as per the manifest, and confirmed in spot check of the actual segment).