# Chromecast error: queue segment (2643656) as segment duration will go beyond buffer limit

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have an m3u8 video that gives this error on the Chromecast:

```
queue segment (2643656) as segment duration will go beyond buffer limit
```

I have the same error if using the reference cast receiver, however two other apps I tried do not have that error. So what are they changing to get around that issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check the solution provided by the Google here in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821022/5995040), it suggested to shorten the length of your segments, which, in general, is recommended to be not more than 10 or at most 15 seconds. Hope this helps.

Comment: That was actually my post for a similar error before, however back then no other app could play that video, now several apps can play this one video. I filed a bug with google and they are looking at it, hopefully I'll find out more soon.

Comment: You could also post that bug link here so that the community would be aware and be updated.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75272527